# Are these two connections to ADO.NET the same (with connection pooling enabled)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ado.net

Is there a problem with the second usage(Code snippet 2)? If so, what is the problem?

```
// ---Code snippet 1---
IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr)
using(connection)
{
    connection.Open(); // Open a connection in “using”
    todo...
}


// ---Code snippet 2---
IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr)
connection.Open(); // Open a connection outside “using”
using(connection) 
{ 
    todo...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement is just built-in language support for correct handling of `IDisposable` objects, using it you can make sure, that your disposable objects are disposed when they should be.

It basically translates to a try-finally pair, with a dispose call in the finally block.
You can read more about the using statement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

That said, you should put the `using` keyword on the first statement you are creating the disposable object, so the correct version of your code would be:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    connection.Open(); // Open a connection in “using”
    todo...
}
```

I don't think the placement of the using keyword makes any difference on what the connection object does or looks like.

Comment: Or in other words: both of the versions in the question are wrong